# Run OpenCL from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, opencl

I've been searching around for some way to easily interface opencl code with MATLAB code, however most of what I've found is several years old and I'm wondering if it's still applicable.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [OpenCL Toolbox](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30109-opencl-toolbox-v0-17)?

Also the [MATLAB Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://au.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/?s_tid=brdcrb) may be a useful alternative if you have the license for it.

Also see [Jacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacket_(software)).

The last two may require you to rewrite your code in the matlab language, if that is an acceptable price.